# Timeout problems during deployment in Android Virtual Device (AVD)?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

when I open AVD (Android Virtual Device) few minute later I face timeout issues during development . how can I increase the default timeout in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this steps
***01. Window

02. Preferences

03. Android

04. DDMS and

05. ADB connection timeout (in ms).***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Prefrences>Android>DDMS>and set ADB connection time

Answer (score 0):

Select ***Window*** → ***Preferences*** → ***Android*** → ***DDMS*** and increase the ADB connection timeout (in ms) value.